# Rails ActveRecord can no longer find rows after migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Everything was working fine and dandy before, with this controller/view

```
def testo
  @positions = Positions.find(:all)
  @comments = Comment.find(:all)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
  end
end
```

View code:

```
.navcon.sprite-gear.sprite
  .notifications.ajaxapp
    .na_head NOTIFICATIONS
      - @comments.each do |comment|
        .na_item
          .na_shell
```

I added a column to the "Comments" table through a migration, and now the @comments variable is coming back undefined. The funny thing is that none of this code was changed, all the records in the database still exists, (I can get them fine in console with the same commands as used in the controller)

```
class AddColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column('comments', 'position', 'text')
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

The error can be seen here:
http://funjable.com/acc_error.html

Comment: Check in rails console could you see these records by just typing "Commant.all" or not?

Comment: Yes they are all returned in console with .all and with .find(:all)

Comment: `@comments` should return same as `Comment.find(:all)` in the rails console... Put the Full Trace of that error here for us to help further....

Comment: Added a link to the error

Comment: Supposedly a similar problem was caused by sqlite3 gem instead of sqlite3-ruby. I do have the plain sqlite3 installed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492209/unable-to-reverse-seemingly-simple-rails-migration-getting-altered-table-colu

Comment: Does it work again when you rollback the migration?

Comment: Yes the rollback got it working again...Any thing in the migration itself that could have caused it?

Comment: How does rollback even work when the down method is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your migration to:

```
def change
   add_column :comments, :position, :text
end
```

I would also suggest giving your migration a more descriptive name (unless you shortened it for us, than never mind :))